# Combine Stop/Reload/Go Buttons in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, xubuntu

Is there an easy way to combine the stop/reload/go buttons in Firefox, using a userstyle? I have a user style that combines stop/reload buttons, but I'd like to combine it with the go button to. The go button would be stop if the page is loading, or reload if it was loaded, and when I focus into the address bar it would turn into the Go button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the Stop/Reload buttons in Firefox just using a little CSS.  Create a `userChrome.css` file in your firefox profile's chrome directory (`%APPDATA%/mozilla/firefox.######.default/chrome` on windows or `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/chrome/` on linux).  In it put the following CSS rules:

```
/* combine stop and reload buttons */
#stop-button[disabled] { display: none }
#stop-button:not([disabled]) + #reload-button { display: none }
```

Now either the stop or reload button will display, not both.  Pretty handy, and saves you from having to install more addons.  Helps make for a very clean Firefox layout:

[image]

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/5360263/maximize-firefox-35s-viewing-area-for-your-netbook)